# Excel 2010 clips top edge of content

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, alignment

In Excel 2010 on 2 different computers, the same file opens differently as follows:

Correct:
[image: Correct]

Incorrect:
[image: incorrect]

The correct one is displayed first. This is a file exported from a SQL Server Report; when most of us export it displays correctly, but on one computer when they export it displays incorrectly and trims the top edge (compare the two 'navigation' column headings that should display `BI Navigation`. When the other person uses save and send, or saves and attaches it to an email, the same file opens correctly on my computer. I've tried to recreate the problem by adjusting screen resolution to various settings, I've been through Excel's options and I can't see anything that might be doing this.

Note that the spreadsheet export has a number of tabs with the same layout, but where the column headings are different (ie shorter or longer text), the row height that contains the column headings does adjust to fit, but still trims the characters.

Note also that resizing the row height either using autofit by resizing manually does not fix it; the top edge is still clipped.

Comment: Are all the computers using the same version of Excel? Is the exported report a `CSV` or `XLS` file? Is the formatting coming from the SQL server? I would expect the server to simply export data, not formatting. Have you tried to import the data from the file into a clean sheet?

Comment: @CharlieRB It's formatted XLS, it's SSRS report hosted on Sharepoint, so it preserves formatting that was created in visual studio. When I export in the same way on other computers it works fine. On their PC when they copy the cells and paste them elsewhere they're still clipped

Comment: And all the computers are using the same version of Excel? If not, that could be part of why its different. All updates for Office installed? I am not familiar with SharePoint to know if there is something related to it which could possibly be causing this.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes everything identical as far as I can tell. The report in Sharepoint generates a .xls file, but the URL is the same so I'm guessing it must be something in Excel itself that is causing it

Comment: make a new column to the left, do you see part of the South in the A column?  To create this problem in a new workbook, Go to a blank work book, Type the word South in a A column cell, change the background to green. Change the format to custom with '@  "               " the And sign plus a quote and some space.  This problem can come from an embedded tab and other weird things.